# Facebook Unity 6.1 SDK crashes on iOS 5.1 device

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Facebook SDK 6.1 beta is crashing iOS 5.1.1 devices.

After compiling the project, I am getting errors in XCode

Any idea how to fix it?

Here is the error:

2014-11-13 09:56:23.597 MyApp[124:707] -> registered mono modules 0xf67e20
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
Mono path[0] = '/var/mobile/Applications/6CE4B4D7-E92C-4B50-BF9F-01FDC1A30211/MyApp.app/Data/Managed'
Mono config path = '/var/mobile/Applications/6CE4B4D7-E92C-4B50-BF9F-01FDC1A30211/MyApp.app/Data/Managed'
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/6CE4B4D7-E92C-4B50-BF9F-01FDC1A30211/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/6CE4B4D7-E92C-4B50-BF9F-01FDC1A30211/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

Comment: Well, it's clear from the code and errors you've posted that the problem is... hey, wait a minute...

Comment: Sorry about that, After rolling back to 6.0 it worked so I didn't have the error, I just installed new SDK 6.1 and reproduced it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 6.1 they updated the underlying Android and iOS SDKs to version 3.17. In the [release notes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x/) for the iOS SDK, they mention that v3.17+ requires iOS 6.0+.